# override global variable and return in another function javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, return-value

How do I get currentQuestion is updated in createQuestion()
each time that the button is clicked, currentQuestion will updating *1, but in the createQuestion() function, the value of currentQuestion is still 0.

```
var currenQuestion = 0;

function nxtQuestion() {
    var button = document.getElementById('nextQuestion');
    document.getElementById('genralCulture').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        if (event.target == button) {
            currenQuestion += 1;
            //createQuestion();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
}

function createQuestion() {
    var question = document.getElementById('theQuestion');
    if (currenQuestion < allQuestions.length) {
        nxtQuestion();
        question.innerHTML = allQuestions[currenQuestion].question;
    } else {
        question.innerHTML = "Your score is "
    }
}
```

In others words, when I click in the button, the question is not updating, but event handlers works properly

Comment: where are you calling `createQuestion()`?

Comment: In the html file. but early, I've call the function in the bottom of js file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var currenQuestion = 0;

function nxtQuestion() {
var button = document.getElementById('nextQuestion');
document.getElementById('genralCulture').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target == button) {
        currenQuestion += 1;
        //createQuestion();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
}

function createQuestion() {
 currenQuestion += 1;
var question = document.getElementById('theQuestion');
if (currenQuestion < allQuestions.length) {
    nxtQuestion();
    question.innerHTML = allQuestions[currenQuestion].question;
} else {
    question.innerHTML = "Your score is "
}
}
```

Comment: could you create JSFiddle please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g77qg/ that adds event listener properly. You should be able to figure it out from this point